# Does Three.js sphere geometry have a size limit?

Tags: three.js

I am making a Three.js sphere geometry with a radius of 4000, put a [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) image on it and position the camera within its center and it works fine.

When I made the sphere with a radius of 9000 so the texture should look further away, it appeared as if there was a black "hole" in the sphere in the very direction the camera was looking. Also the texture on the sphere looks nearer and not further away. When I move the camera towards this "hole" it becomes smaller.

```
new THREE.SphereGeometry(9000, 32, 32);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camera has a .near and .far setting. If .far is lower than your sphere radius, it will clip like you are describing.
Try setting camera.far = 20000

Comment: You nailed it, pal. The "black hole" is gone.